# 2.80 - Can't see selection color

Tags: selection-tools, grease-pencil

On this project I'm working on, when I select a vertex (or anything else) in edit mode it doesn't become orange, it looks exactly like if it wasn't selected. If I grab it, however, I can see the vertex move, so I know it has been selected even if it doesn't show.

I've tried this on a new file and the vertex is shown orange when selected like expected, so it seems like I changed some setting without realizing it in the original project. Does anyone know what is going on?

EDIT: forgot to mention that this happens with the grease pencil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was rather simple: somehow the vertex opacity in the overlay menu was set to 0. Changing its value fixed it.

[image]